# NodeJS - passport-local-mongoose error on starting the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport-local

The code below give out error on starting the server. The code is from a course on coursera based on nodejs, express and mongodb. I have tried to rectify the error and even copy the code given in the course but neither worked. The error that the terminal shows is in the index.js of passport-local-mongoose module making me believe that there is something that I did wrong while its implementation. Kindly help me solve this.

On starting the server it prints,

```
ent/home/sanket/VSCode/NodeJS/conFusionServer/node_modules/passport-local-mongoose/index.js:125
  .then(({ user }) => {
         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sanket/VSCode/NodeJS/conFusionServer/models/users.js:3:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sanket/VSCode/NodeJS/conFusionServer/authenticate.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
```

Here are the files related to this error,

models/users.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var User = new Schema({
    admin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
});
User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

routes/users.js

```
var express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var User = require('../models/users');
var passport = require('passport');
var router = express.Router();
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});
router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
  User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), 
    req.body.password, (err, user) => {
    if(err) {
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json({err: err});
    }
    else {
      passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, () => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.json({success: true, status: 'Registration Successful!'});
      });
    }
  });
});
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.json({success: true, status: 'You are successfully logged in!'});
});
router.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.session) {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.clearCookie('session-id');
    res.redirect('/');
  }
  else {
    var err = new Error('You are not logged in!');
    err.status = 403;
    next(err);
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

authenticate.js

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('./models/users');

exports.local = passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);
var passport = require('passport');
var authenticate = require('./authenticate');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var dishRouter = require('./routes/dishRouter');
var promoRouter = require('./routes/promoRouter');
var leaderRouter = require('./routes/leaderRouter');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Dishes = require('./models/dishes');

const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion';
const connect = mongoose.connect(url);

connect.then((db) => {
    console.log('Connected correctly to the server');
}, (err) => { 
    console.log(err); 
});

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(session({
  name: 'session-id',
  secret: '12345-67890-09876-54321',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  store: new FileStore()
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

function auth (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.user) {
    var err = new Error('You are not authenticated!');
    err.status = 403;
    return next(err);
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
}

app.use(auth);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/dishes', dishRouter);
app.use('/promotions', promoRouter);
app.use('/leaders', leaderRouter);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Here is the link for the course [Server-side Development with NodeJS, Express and MongoDB](https://www.coursera.org/learn/server-side-nodejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line in authenticate.js file

```
exports.local = passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
```

with

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
```

It should work.

This is my thread
https://www.coursera.org/learn/server-side-nodejs/discussions/weeks/3/threads/zVHS6leUSwOR0upXlOsD0Q

If it does not work please tell.